# How to catch all characters with slashes after domain address with mod_rewrite as one parameter?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

How to catch all characters after domain name as one parameter with mod_rewrite?
I have script which load other page content and displays that like standard page. 
example script address look like that:

```
example.com/script.php/?www='/some/paths/etc'
```

I want to mask that URL to look like this:

```
example.com/some/paths/etc
```

If no paths exist it should look like

```
example.com/
```

There can be different amount of URL parts (a/b/c/.../X/)

I red about mod_proxy but I can do it with only .htaccess so it doesn't solve my problem.
I can't redirect one address to other, they have to be separated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *proxy* via `mod_rewrite` (as long as `mod_proxy` has been compiled into the server), and this can be done via .htaccess files. Note that `RewriteEngine On` requires `Options FollowSymLinks` to be overridable in your .htaccess.

The following in your .htaccess file:

```
 Options FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/script.php/?www=
 RewriteRule ^/script.php/?www='([^']+)' http://example.com/$1
 RewriteRule ^/(.*) /script.php/?www='$1' [P]
```

The `RewriteCond` matches your script path with a ?www= argument (if it fails to match no rewrite will take place). The first `RewriteRule` will match the www= argument and rewrite the *visible* path of the request. The second `RewriteRule` will then *proxy* the request (due to the **[P]** flag) to the script and will get the "content".

Note: this has not been tested, but hopefully will get you heading in the right direction to solve the problem. Also if script.php expects optional args `&var2=whatever` you will probably need to tweak the `RewriteCond` to match that and store it using parentheses. You can then recall those args using %1. More details can be found in the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Also to help you debug your rewriting you can use:

```
RewriteLog /full/path/to/your/log/file
RewriteLogLevel 3
```

**EDIT:** Added the `RewriteLog` stuff an clarified that the snippet at the top is to be put in the .htaccess file

Comment: `RewriteRule` _does not work_ with query string _directly_ -- only with help of `RewriteCond`. Therefore this part `RewriteRule ^/script.php/?www='([^']+)'` makes no sense.

Comment: @Drav Sloan: I didn't checked if your code is correct but your answer gave me some other ideas how to solve my problem. Thanks.